# commands.HelpCommand implementation

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to customize the `!help` command of my Discord bot using [`commands.HelpCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand), but I'm note sure to understand how it works.

My actual (minimal) code is the following:

```py
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx, *, command=None):
    hc = commands.HelpCommand()
    await hc.command_callback(ctx, command=command)
```

But I encounter this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/bot.py", line 229, in help
    await hc.command_callback(ctx, command=command)
  File "[...]/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/help.py", line 782, in command_callback
    mapping = self.get_bot_mapping()
  File "[...]/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/help.py", line 331, in get_bot_mapping
    bot = self.context.bot
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'
```

I understand that `HelpCommand.command_callback` needs `HelpCommand.context` to be set... but [the doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand.context) states that

> This (`context`) is generally set after the help command assigned, `command_callback()`, has been called.

That sounds like a bug for me, but I'm not sure to fully understand how to implement `HelpCommand`...
I tried to move it into a cog, to pass `context=ctx` to `HelpCommand` during initialization and other things, without success.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if it can help anyone, I just noticed the [`help_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command) parameter of  `commands.Bot`...
You just have to pass it your `HelpCommand` instance!

No need to do any tricky workaround, I was indeed misunderstanding things.